# Upgrading Doctrine in a Symfony 2.8 application

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I need to update to Doctrine 2.5 for a bundle which requires it (Vich\UploaderBundle). However I am facing two difficulties:

1. How do I know which Doctrine version is compatible with my Symfony 2.8 setup
2. How do I actually run the upgrade

Composer management is still quite obscure to me, especially the output you get when you try to update.

Here is my current composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "files": ["app/AppKernel.php"]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "apy/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
    "pagerfanta/pagerfanta":           "dev-master",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "dev-master",
    "idci/admin-generator-bundle":     "dev-master",
    "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "v3.2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
    "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "~2.0",
    "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "~2.3",
    "robertotru/to-inline-style-email-bundle": "dev-master",

},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
},
"require-dev": {
}
}
```

---

[EDIT]
Specified require doctrine version.
I also have the feeling that this composer.json needs to be cleaned up somehow but that's another question...

Comment: One approach that often works is to create a new S2.8 project and then examine it's composer.json.  It really looks like all you did was to bump Symfony from 2.3 to 2.8?  And you have quite a few dev-master items in there.  Going to take some effort I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seem to come from this strict restriction on the dependency : "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*" which require "doctrine/orm" < 2.5 (see here : https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-bundle#v1.2.0)

The solution might be to upgrade the version of this first dependency to

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6"
```

I didn't check the compatibility with all others packages so i'm not completly sure but you still can try.